# ¿cómo consultar en SQL todos los registros que coincidan exactamente con todos los items de una lista/array?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql

Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo una tabla de ítems y luego tengo una tabla de servicios que se relaciona con esos ítems.

Quisiera buscar todos los servicios que contengan un listado de ítems (ejemplo: item1,item2,item3). Ojo, deben ser todos los servicios que tengan solo esos tres ítems juntos y no alguno de ellos como lo hace el IN(item1,item2,item3)

¿cómo podría realizar esa consulta? actualmente uso el IN y me trae todos los registros que contengan al menos uno de los items

Comment: Podes mostrar un ejemplo de los datos que tenes?

Comment: Si la quieres hacer facil y tediosa, hazlo con `where col=item1 and col2=item2 and col3=item3`, pero intenta indicar mejor que estás preguntando, podrías mostrar que haz intentado e incluso sería de ayuda una ejemplo representativo de las tablas en caso que no quieras mostrar el esquema (no deberías mostrarlo, pero si algo representativo)

Answer (score 0):

Solo se me ocurre que puedes usar un having count

En caso de que sean siempre la misma cantidad de valores (3 en tu ejemplo)

```
SELECT  Columna1
FROM    Tabla
WHERE   Columna2 IN ('Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3')
GROUP   BY Columna1
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 3
```

En caso de que no conozcas la cantidad de valores

```
SELECT  Columna1
FROM    Tabla
WHERE   Columna2 IN ('Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3')
GROUP   BY Columna1
HAVING  COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLA WHERE CONDICIONES.....)
```

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, el Query seria el siguiente:

```
 SELECT  S.servicio
 FROM    items I
 INNER JOIN servicios S ON S.id=I.id
 WHERE I.item IN ('Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3')
 HAVING  COUNT(*) = 3 ;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sirva, saludos!